# Countdown Timer Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I have been looking for a count down timer on google and can't seem to find one.
I was just wondering if anyone would be able to help.
I got given one but it displays the wrong times.

I want it to display days, hours, minutes and seconds left.
 heres what I need the timer on

http://pastebin.com/fQjyRFXw

It already has the timer code there but it's all wrong, any help would be great, thank you

If it's helps here's a snippet of the Java code

```
var count = <?= $time['a_time'] ?>;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will* run it every 1 second
function timer() {
    count = count - 1;
    if(count == -1) {
        clearInterval(counter); 
        return;
    }
    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60); 
    minutes %= 60; 
    hours %= 60; 
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hours + "hours " + minutes + "minutes and " + seconds + " seconds left"; 
}
```

Comment: What is the format of `a_time`?

Comment: Unix I'm pretty sure

Comment: Okay then maybe it will help if you place a `console.log(count);` in `timer()` function and check the logs.

Comment: Yeah maybe, check the pastebin link, will give you more of an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I see your problem. The `a_time` stored in database is an Unix timestamp, thus when you are counting down, you need to know how long is between `now` and `a_time` instead of only `a_time`.

Try this:

```
var count = <?= $time['a_time'] ?>;
var now = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
count = count - now;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will* run it every 1 second
function timer() {
  count = count - 1;
  if(count == -1) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    return;
  }
  var seconds = count % 60;
  var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
  var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
  var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
  minutes %= 60;
  hours %= 24;
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = days + "days " + hours + "hours " + minutes + "minutes and " + seconds + " seconds left";
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, now the only problem I have now is its not properly counting days, it will say 28 hours, instead of 1 day 4 hours. Any idea to this mate?

Comment: Anyone able to help me with this please?

Comment: Thank you I will test it out now and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Why not use one of the man examples on codepen such as this beautiful one 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeLWdz ?

```
(function (e) {
    e.fn.countdown = function (t, n) {
    function i() {
        eventDate = Date.parse(r.date) / 1e3;
        currentDate = Math.floor(e.now() / 1e3);
        if (eventDate <= currentDate) {
            n.call(this);
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
        seconds = eventDate - currentDate;
        days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
        seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
        hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
        seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        seconds -= minutes * 60;
        days == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day") : thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("days");
        hours == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hour") : thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours");
        minutes == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minute") : thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minutes");
        seconds == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("second") : thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("seconds");
        if (r["format"] == "on") {
            days = String(days).length >= 2 ? days : "0" + days;
            hours = String(hours).length >= 2 ? hours : "0" + hours;
            minutes = String(minutes).length >= 2 ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
            seconds = String(seconds).length >= 2 ? seconds : "0" + seconds
        }
        if (!isNaN(eventDate)) {
            thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
            thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
            thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
            thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds)
        } else {
            alert("Invalid date. Example: 30 Tuesday 2013 15:50:00");
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
    }
    var thisEl = e(this);
    var r = {
        date: null,
        format: null
    };
    t && e.extend(r, t);
    i();
    interval = setInterval(i, 1e3)
    }
    })(jQuery);
    $(document).ready(function () {
    function e() {
        var e = new Date;
        e.setDate(e.getDate() + 60);
        dd = e.getDate();
        mm = e.getMonth() + 1;
        y = e.getFullYear();
        futureFormattedDate = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + y;
        return futureFormattedDate
    }
    $("#countdown").countdown({
        date: "1 April 2017 09:00:00", // Change this to your desired date to countdown to
        format: "on"
    });
});
```

Comment: Cheers, I will try this.

Comment: If it doesnt work out there are plenty of others on there as well. I just did a search for countdown date.

Comment: Thanks I will sure have a look mate, this one looks like.html am I correct? I'm just really looking for a simple fix to the current one I have its just not calculating days and hours correctly